# What is the value of these integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

What is the value of this :

> - $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(nt)\,dt$ where $f\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ and
> - $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos^2(nt) \, dt$ where $f\in C[-\pi,\pi]$

What is the general idea behind this ? **Integration by parts** is not working here.I don't why the answer is given to be **$0$**.

Comment: The answers are not zero for some continuous function $f$. Would you please check? Maybe you need $f$ is an odd function to conclude the values are $0$?

Comment: Ar you sure? Take $f(x)=\cos nx$

Comment: Your integral limits and the bounds of your space don't match.. Is this how it should be or is it a typo?

Comment: sorry for the mistake;please excuse @Mattos@ S.W.Cheung

Comment: Read about Riemman-Lebesgue Lemma